# Write Number in Expanded Form

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing some code exercise, it is about to create a function `expandedForm` to take a number parameter, the example in below would be more clear..

```
expandedForm(12); // Should return '10 + 2'
expandedForm(42); // Should return '40 + 2'
expandedForm(70304); // Should return '70000 + 300 + 4'
```

My solution:

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
  // Your code here
  let numStr = num.toString().split('');
  
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numStr; i++ ){
      
      for(let y = numStr.length; y > 1; y--){
         numStr[i] += '0'; 
         // console.log(y);  use this to debug y, and no y value print out from console
      }
  }
  
  return numStr.join('+')
}

console.log(expandedForm(23));
```

if I test expandedForm(23), the result is '2+3', also the y value hasn't print to the console, can anyone tell me what wrong with my solution? thank you.

---

## Solution

Thanks everyone, thanks for pointing out my `variable y` initial in for loop is not correct, and `i < numStr` as well (silly mistake).

After review my code and inspired by some suggestions below, my final solution is

```
 function expandedForm(num) {
      // Your code here
      let numStr = num.toString().split('');
      
      for(let i = 0 ; i < numStr.length; i++ ){
          
          for(let y = numStr.length - i; y > 1; y--){
             numStr[i] += '0'; 
             // console.log(y);  use this to debug y, and no y value print out from console
          }
      }
      
     
      numStr = numStr.filter(value => !value.startsWith(0));
      return numStr.join(' + ')
    }

    console.log(expandedForm(23));
```

Comment: `i < numStr` that will be `false`, so you never go into the first loop: `0 < ["2", "3"]`

Answer (score 1):

First, numStr is an array, so you cannot use i < numStr (0 < ["2", "3"]).

Second, `for(let y = numStr.length; y > 1; y--)` the range value of y not change in each for i loop.

Right solution with the least change in your code:

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
  // Your code here
  let numStr = num.toString().split('');
  
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numStr.length; i++ ){
      for(let y = numStr.length - i; y > 1; y--){
         numStr[i] += '0'; 
      }
  }
  
  return numStr.join('+')
}

console.log(expandedForm(23));
```

Sorry my english very bad :(

Comment: I don't think the two loops are needed, either - seems like one should be sufficient. But that's not on you, it's a commentary on OP's code, you just made his original idea work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const expandedForm = n => n.toString()
                            .split("")
                            .reverse()
                            .map( (a, i) => a * Math.pow(10, i))
                            .filter(a => a > 0)
                            .reverse()
                            .join(" + ");

console.log(expandedForm(70304));
```

This is a chain of methods that can be used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function expandedForm(num) {
  let str = String(num).split('');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ){
      for(let j = str.length - i; j > 1; j--){
        if(str[i] == '0'){
          i++;
        }else{
         str[i] += '0'; 
        }
      }
  }
  
  return str.filter(item => item != '0').join(' + ');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize second loop y with (numStr.length -i) because in expanded form the zeroes should be reduced with every iteration, unlike your case which was constant.

also you need to filter the result and remove the zero in case of "70000 + 0+ 300 + 0 + 4 " ==> "70000 + 300 + 4 " using filter 
numStr = numStr.filter(value => value !== '0');

This should print the correct expanded form

```js
function expandedForm(num) {
  // Your code here
  let numStr = num.toString().split('');

  for(let i = 0 ; i < numStr.length; i++ ){
      if(numStr[i]!=0){
      for(let y = (numStr.length-i); y > 1; y--){
         numStr[i] += '0'; 
          //console.log(y);  //use this to debug y, and no y value print out from console
      }
     }
  }

  numStr = numStr.filter(value => value !== '0');
  return numStr.join('+')
}

console.log(expandedForm(23));
```